# How to solve truncated text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, I made image and add text under image, but the text is truncated (image below)

[image: Screen shot]

I do the following :

```
body: new TabBarView(
        children: [
          new Scaffold(
            body: GridView.count(
              primary: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 100.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      decoration: gradientBackDecoration(),
                      child: new ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        child: Image.asset("src/images/2way.jpg",
                            height: 167.0, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      '2 Way',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontFamily: "AbrilFatFace",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
    ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      decoration: gradientBackDecoration(),
                      child: new ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        child: Image.asset("src/images/andycaldwell.jpg",
                            height: 167.0, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'Andy Caldwell',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontFamily: "AbrilFatFace",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

I have updated my code.

I expect the text looks more bigger, centered and not truncated.
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: The image shows a grid while in code sample you are using ListView. Are you sure you have posted the same  code as in  the screenshot?

Comment: i'm sure, btw i have updated my code, maybe you can check there

Comment: try replacing ListView with a colum

Comment: did that already lol, and it says "bottom overfllowed by 16 pixels" so i try change to listView

Comment: you can use the aspect ratio value to be 0.8 and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in a grid view when the aspect ration is 1, the width and height of its children is same. For a vertically scrolling gridview it first calculates the available screen to fit the width which then determines its height.

In the above scenario the height was as big as the width of the item, which was not allowing the text to show. Adjust the aspect ratio(0.8 worked for me) and that should work. If you want to be more precise then use SliverGridDelegate.

Comment: ah great, I just change the aspect ratio to 0.8 and it works like charm, thanks bro